# Database Drive Rule Engine Using NRules

Tags: c#, .net, validationrules, nrules

I am creating a business rule engine and planning to user NRules framework.
https://github.com/NRules/NRules
But I want to know if I can generate rule from database it self.

I have a database table which has some rule saved.
Age    >    20
Name    == 'John'

Condition can be multiple, Nothing is hard-coded even property name can change.

I cam across an blog post which does the same but using expression trees.
http://coding-time.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-implement-rule-engine-in-c.html

Can I achieve same by using the NRules framework, if yes, where I can find some code samples.

Comment: Hi. Did you find the solution?